# What are the general consideration for tendon profile in a post tension slab?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, prestressed-concrete

How the tendon profile is calculated for banded-distributed disposition? In the following figure why is the tendons profile one in the top fiber and the second in the bottom fiber? If the location is at the middle of the slab why do we place them opposite to each other doesn't that cancel the effect of the lower tendon?

[image: tendon opposite to each others]

maybe this picture will clear my question

[image: load in interior panel]

Comment: There are at least three separate questions in there. They are all slightly different. Which one do you have?

Comment: all the questions are related I am asking How the tendon profile is calculated because I know how the general profile Is (in the middle low point and at the support high point) but since I saw the picture above I was wondering that does always is the case that is why I'm asking all these questions at the same time.